# Can SOLR datetime queries use only days or must I specify the whole ISO-8601 string with time

Tags: date, datetime, solr

I want to make a search for SOLR documents for a specific date.

I found doc page (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates) that says I can just specify the date like 2016-11-23 and it should search for all documents on this specific date.

I also found a Stackoverflow question that states the same [How to filter query in solr by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977389/how-to-filter-query-in-solr-by-date)

But when I try it in the SOLR update panel I always get "Invalid Date String:'2016-11-23'"

What I wanted to know now: is it possible to use the dates in this format without time or do I have to provide the whole datetime string always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples from the format above is valid for fields of the type `DateRangeField` only, and not for regular date fields.

The easiest way to work around this for regular date fields is to append `T00:00:00Z` to your range:

```
fq=date:[2016-11-23T00:00:00Z TO 2016-11-24T00:00:00Z}
```

The reason for using `}` is that you don't want to include documents with `00:00:00` the following day.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the '}' character. I didn't know that.